# How do I make a user management and login module with roles in a separate table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

The problem I have is this: I have in my requirements a Users table and a Roles table separated.

> users(id, login, password, id_role, name, last name, telephone, ...)
>   roles(id, role, description)

I already have read and followed the authentication example [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) but it has the role in the same table as the user's data. I don't know how can I relate both tables in cakePHP, especially in a login module. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why don't you Try belongsTo relation?? Something like User belongsTo  
Role

Comment: Have you read the book? I guess no. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html Read this link for your model linking problem and do the blog tutorial to get a minimum of understanding of CakePHP instead of starting blindly hacking code together.

Comment: Well the authentication example I posted the link to is a sequel to the blog tutorial so yeah I have a minimum understanding of cakePHP. I have read the link you posted but I don't totally understand how to make something out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the CakePHP cookbook. The next topic after the simple authentication and authorization chapter is how to build an ACL-controlled application, which is what you’re after: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Change field `roles` to `role_id` and add relation Role hasMany User (User belongsTo Role)